# Embed a property or method on the app object inside of controller

Tags: javascript, kraken.js

I´m trying associate a method or a property on a `app` object in kraken.js application, like follows:

**controllers/index.js**

```
'use strict';

var IndexModel = require('../models/index');


module.exports = function (app) {

    var model = new IndexModel();
    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
        console.log(app.adventurer);
        /* Console should be showing "Bilbo Bagins", but I'm getting 'undefined'.
         * See the next source file. */
        res.render('index', model);        
    });

};
```

**/index.js**

```
var kraken = require('kraken-js'),
    app = {
        adventurer: 'Bilbo Bagins'
    };


app.configure = function configure(nconf, next) {
    // Async method run on startup.
    next(null);
};


app.requestStart = function requestStart(server) {
    // Run before most express middleware has been registered.
};


app.requestBeforeRoute = function requestBeforeRoute(server) {
    // Run before any routes have been added.
};


app.requestAfterRoute = function requestAfterRoute(server) {
    // Run after all routes have been added.
};


if (require.main === module) {
    kraken.create(app).listen(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.stack);
        }
    });
}


module.exports = app;
```

Also, i´ve tried publish the property on `/config/app.json`

Any Thoughts?

Comment: The 'app' var is not the same thing in each of your files.  In controllers/index.js it is the instance of the Express application NOT the instance of 'app' you create in /index.js.  That's why you don't see your adventurer property.

Comment: @Matthew nice, to know that is a different instances. This is helpful.  Now i think I´ll update the question to question about app inside of controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following key to .config/app.json or make a new .config/app-development.json:

```
"adventurer": "bilbo"
```

app.json will look like this:

```
{
//blah
//blah
"adventurer": "bilbo"
}
```

and then in ./index.js do this in configure:

```
app.configure = function configure(nconf, next) {
    // Async method run on startup.
    next(null);
    console.log('my traveler is: ', nconf.get('adventurer'));
};
```

In response to your comment, if you want to get an app config from the ./controllers/index.js then require the nconf lib and use nconf.get like so:

```
'use strict';
var nconf = require('nconf');

var IndexModel = require('../models/index');

module.exports = function (app) {

    var model = new IndexModel();

    //or attach it directly to the app object like so
    app.set('adventurer', nconf.get('adventurer'));
    console.log('adventurer directly set on app object', app.get('adventurer'));

    console.log('controller with app adventurer:', nconf.get('adventurer'));

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {

        res.render('index', model);

    });

};
```

Fire it up with npm start and watch the console. Peace!

Comment: Thats dont solves the problem i need the property inside of controller callback. Like a said into **/controllers/index.js**